# Responsive <table> images for emails

Tags: html, email, html-table, responsive-images

I'm trying to make the images responsive to mobile devices without success.

Thank you

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" max-width="100%" height="auto"; >
            <img max-width="100%"; !important; src="https://i.ibb.co/TqP2gBh/sky-email.png" alt="sky" style="display: block;" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td max-width="100%" height="auto";>
        <img max-width="100%"; src="https://i.ibb.co/qygC43j/eader-email.png" alt="header"   style="display: block; " /> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
        </td><a href="https://evyatarmor.com">  <img width="100%";  src="https://i.ibb.co/G7FWJf3/portfolio-email.png" alt="button" style="display: block;" />
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 0 100px 0px;" width="100%" height="auto";>
        <img max-width="100%"; src="https://i.ibb.co/P5b9KTb/green-email.png" alt="header" style="display: block;" /> 
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing the appropriate responsive tag in the head:
2. Max-width is not an attribute, it should be defined in the style block as a CSS property.
3. You have an open tags or missing tags all over the show here. It's going to cause issues with responsive working as well as general rendering.

Please, in future supply properly structured code so we can debug as in it's current state, it's difficult to see what is going on here.
I've taken a guess and removed anything that isn't closed as there is no context given:

```html
<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
  
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width:500px){
      .wrapper{ width:100% !important; }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="wrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" max-width="100%" height="auto"; >
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x150" alt="sky" style="display: block; max-width:100%;" /> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x150" alt="header"   style="display: block; max-width:100%;" /> 
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="https://evyatarmor.com">  <img width="100%" src="https://i.ibb.co/G7FWJf3/portfolio-email.png" alt="button" style="display: block;" /></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 0 100px 0px;">
              <img max-width="100%"; src="https://i.ibb.co/P5b9KTb/green-email.png" alt="header" style="display: block;" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```